# How can I find the number of 2d array rows in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a 2d array in a session variable:

```
$_session['multi'][] = array('item0 ' , 'price0');
$_session['counter']++;

$_session['multi'][] = array('item1 ' , 'price1');
$_session['counter']++;
```

I want to be able to show the array (and put them in the database) like this:

```
$_session['multi'][0][0] , $_session['multi'][0][1]
$_session['multi'][1][0] , $_session['multi'][1][1]
.
.
.
```

I am using a for loop to do that:

```
for(){
    show $_session['multi][i][0] , $_session['multi][i][1]
}
```

But I have to carry a session (counter) with the number of the rows around to use it with the for loop.

Is there any way to get the number of the rows so I can lose the counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the number of items in `$_SESSION['multi']` it's as simple as:

```
count($_SESSION['multi']);
```

Comment: why not simply `count($_SESSION['multi'])` ?

Comment: @Yahick Rochon yes I came to that conclusion in the middle of the night.  The visual representation of them like table rows in the OP had my thinking all clouded.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['multi'] as $row) {
    // $row[0], $row[1] ...
}
```